# Ocultar colspan dinamicamente

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código, el cuál oculta columnas de manera dinamica. El problema es que estoy tratando de agregar un colspan para la primera columna, misma que contiene 2 columnas. Si oculto la primera, solo se oculta la primera que esta dentro de ella y no la segunda en conjunto, descuadrando mi tabla.. ¿Alguien me puede echar una mano por favor? gracias.

```js
   $(document).on("click", "[data-column]", function () {
      var button = $(this),
          header = $(button.data("column")),
          table = header.closest("table"),
          index = header.index() + 1, // convert to CSS's 1-based indexing
          selector = "tbody tr td:nth-child(" + index + ")",
          column = table.find(selector).add(header);

      column.toggleClass("hidden");
    });
```

```css
.hidden { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th id="column-a" colspan="2">Step 1</th>
    <th id="column-b"  colspan="1">Step 2</th>
    <th id="column-c"  colspan="1">Step 3</th>
    </tr>  
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Of step 1</td>
      <td>Of step 1</td>
      <td>Of step 2</td>
      <td>Of step 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Of step 1</td>
      <td>Of step 1</td>
      <td>Of step 2</td>
      <td>Of step 3</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" data-column="#column-a">Hide/show 1st</button>
<button type="button" data-column="#column-b">Hide/show 3rd</button>
<button type="button" data-column="#column-c">Hide/show last</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer seria lo siguiente:

- Sumar el total de `colspan` hasta el `th` a *ocultar/mostrar*.
- El `th` a *ocultar/mostrar*, nos indica la cantidad de columnas que agrupo (eg: `colspan`)
- Con esos 2 datos podemos saber a partir de que `td` y cuantos hay que *ocultar/mostrar*.

Ejemplo:

```js
$(document).on("click", "[data-column]", function () {
  var button = $(this),
      header = $(button.data("column")),
      tr = header.closest("tr"),
      table = header.closest("table"),
      index = header.index(),
      prevColspans = 0,
      colspan = parseInt(header.attr('colspan'), 10),
      selectors = [];
   
   // Obtenemos el total de columnas anteriores al header acutal
   for (var i = 0; i < index; i++) {
     prevColspans += parseInt(tr.children().eq(i).attr('colspan'), 10);
   }
   
   // Por cada col agrupada
   for (i = 0; i < colspan; i++) {
      selectors.push("tbody tr td:nth-child(" + (i + prevColspans + 1) + ")");
    }
    table.find(selectors.join(',')).add(header).toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th id="column-a" colspan="2">Step 1</th>
    <th id="column-b" colspan="1">Step 2</th>
    <th id="column-c" colspan="1">Step 3</th>
    </tr>  
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Of step 1</td>
      <td>Of step 1</td>
      <td>Of step 2</td>
      <td>Of step 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Of step 1</td>
      <td>Of step 1</td>
      <td>Of step 2</td>
      <td>Of step 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" data-column="#column-a">Hide/show 1st</button>
<button type="button" data-column="#column-b">Hide/show 3rd</button>
<button type="button" data-column="#column-c">Hide/show last</button>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, esto es lo que necesitaba. 
Saludos!